# Using strncpy on struct

Tags: c, struct, char, constants, strncpy

Let's say I have this `student struct` defined:

```
struct student {
    char *name;
};
typedef struct student Student
```

Now I have the following function:

```
void add_student(const char *student_name) {

    // create new student
    Student *new_s;
    new_s = malloc(sizeof(Student));

    strncpy(new_s->name, student_name, sizeof(new_s->name) - 1)
}
```

I want to add the student_name to the name of the new student struct. However because `const char` and `char` are different I have to use `strncpy`.

I tried it this way, however I get a segmentation fault, what's wrong?

Comment: Instead of `strncpy` you may want to take a look at `strdup`. It sounds very close to what you try to archive here.

Comment: **NEVER use `strncpy`** it is never the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only allocating memory for the structure `new_s` in this line

```
new_s = malloc(sizeof(Student));
```

This includes the variable `char* name`, which is a `pointer to a char`. Although, you also need memory to which this pointer will point at.

So, you need to allocate memory for the character pointer `name` inside the structure.

```
// create new student
Student *new_s;
new_s = malloc(sizeof(Student));

new_s->name = malloc(100); //assuming you need to store a string of len 100
```

Comment: so after allocating new_s->name, i can use strncpy as such?
strncpy(new_group->name, group_name, <what would go here?>)

Comment: @bakedturtle, The only problem was that you did not allocate the memory. Otherwise your code should work after you add that line. why don't you run and check.

Comment: Hmmm - looks like off-by-1 to me.  "`...100);` --> //assuming you need to store a string of len 100".  The length of a string typically does not include the null character, so suggest "to store a string of length of up to  99".

Answer (score 2):

As Johan Wentholt correctly outlined in his answer, you must allocate memory for both the `Student` structure and the string its member `name` points to, but you must return the new structure so the caller can do something with it:

```
Student *add_student(const char *student_name) {
    Student *new_s = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if (new_s) {
        new_s->name = strdup(student_name);
    }
    return new_s;
}
```

You code invokes undefined behavior because you did not allocate memory for the string, worse even, you left the `name` member uninitialized (`malloc` does not initialize the memory it returns).

Furthermore, you should not use `strncpy`.  It is **not** some safe version of `strcpy`, it is a **very** error prone function, whose semantics are poorly understood by most programmers.  **NEVER use this function**.  If you see it used, there are chances you are either in front of a bug or there is a better method to replace it.

For completeness, your code:

```
strncpy(new_s->name, student_name, sizeof(new_s->name) - 1);
```

- Would attempt to copy at most `sizeof(char*)-1` characters from `student_name` into the array pointer to by `new_s->name`.
- If the `student_name` is longer, the destination will not be null terminated,
- If it is shorter, the destination will be padded with null bytes upto the given size.
- Here the destination pointer is uninitialized and the size information is bogus anyway: you really want to copy all characters in the string plus the null terminator, which is exactly what `strcpy` does.  But you need to allocate enough memory for that. You could use:

  ```
  new_s->data = malloc(strlen(student_name) + 1);
  strcpy(new_s->data, student_name);
  ```

The Posix function `strdup()` does both operations in one call:

```
    new_s->data = strdup(student_name);
```

Comment: This is true, but i was using the example provided by bakedturtle.

Answer (score 1):

Haris gave a good solution. But like Florian Zwoch said in the comments you can also use strdup like so:

```
void add_student(const char *student_name)
{
    Student *new_s = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    new_s->name = strdup(student_name);
}
```

**Keep in mind that you have to `free` `new_s->name` and than `free` `new_s`.**

You should also check the return value of `malloc` and `strdup` for `NULL` value. Since it returns `NULL` if insufficient memory is available.

As side note, you can shorten up the `struct` and `typedef` to one statement like so:

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
} Student;
```